# undistorting points of a circle

Tags: c#, math

I have various `Point` objects which are samples taken along a circle. The points are at various places around the whole circle. Due to camera distortion, the circle isn't a perfect circle - more egg shaped where the bottom half is flatter and slightly more wider than the top half.

How do I map these points to a uniform circle for various calculations?

Answer (score 0):

If points are at random places around the whole circle, it seems rather hard to map points to correct places, if no additional information about transformation/distortion ([example for perspective](http://www.math.utah.edu/~treiberg/Perspect/Perspect.htm#circle) shows that center and circumference points are shifted)

But you can try [OpenCV camera calibration](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html) with [chessboard or grid pattern](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d94/tutorial_camera_calibration.html#gsc.tab=0), if possible.